# Play Framework how to sort collection in repeat() form helper?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Based on [the Play (java) documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers), let's say I have the following example:

```
public class UserForm {
    public String name;
    public List<MyClass> itmes;
}
```

and

```
@helper.inputText(userForm("name"))

@helper.repeat(userForm("items"), min = 1) { itemField =>

    @helper.inputText(itemField)

}
```

However, in `MyClass` I have an overridden implementation of `compareTo()`. I also have a getter `getSortedItems()` that will return the list in the proper sorted order.

Currently, using the `repeat()` helper **does not** get my list of items in the ordering that I want. **Is there a way to specify the ordering for the `repeat()` helper?** Or can I give it a `List` as a parameter? It seems like this would be possible to do in Scala.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't populate items in the appropriately sorted order?

Comment: @ArneClaassen I don't seem to have control of it. Sometimes they get populated in the default order, and then if I update an item in the List it gets pushed to the end of the list. I want to be able to enforce the ordering

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `List<MyClass>` with a sorted set:

```
case class MyClass(id: Int, name: String)
val sorted = new mutable.TreeSet[MyClass]()(new Ordering[MyClass] {
  def compare(a: MyClass, b: MyClass): Int = {
    Ordering.Int.compare(a.id,b.id)
  }
})
sorted.add(MyClass(2,"bob"))
sorted.add(MyClass(1,"bill"))
sorted.add(MyClass(3,"jane"))
```

I assume that list will contain only unique instances of `MyClass`, so a set should work fine and every time you add an item, the set will make sure it stays sorted.

The java version should be pretty close:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyClass {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

public class MyClassComparator implements Comparator<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
       return Integer.compare(a.id,b.id);
    }
}

TreeSet<MyClass> sorted = new TreeSet<>(new MyClassComparator());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with Scala, do you have an example of this in Java?

Comment: Actually I think I understand. I'll try a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) of items.

Comment: So I tried this in my project and I got an exception: `play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'fields[1]' of bean class [models.CSVData]: Illegal attempt to get property 'fields' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'fields[1]' of bean class [models.CSVData]: Cannot get element with index 1 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'fields[1]']]`. Perhaps there is some problem using Ebean with Sets in this way? Or it might be some other problem in my code

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the set was empty, since it failed at getting index 1 and claims the set has a size of 0. Is it possible the set was not properly initialized?